# Do DG methods for the Helmholtz equation always return positive quantities?

Tags: finite-element, discontinuous-galerkin, elliptic-pde

<del>Helmholtz</del> Diffusion equation with reaction term:
$$
k\Delta u + u = f ~ \text{in} ~\Omega
$$
$$
\nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0 ~ \text{in} ~\partial \Omega
$$

For sufficiently small $k$ (relative to the mesh), there can be oscillations (with Lagrange elements) that return a negative $u$ in some regions, specially when $f$ is a step function. I tried to apply a DG method with the Symmetric Interior Penalty formulation, and I am still seeing these negative values. Is this possible to happen? I was told that DG methods preserve positivity and cannot return negative values. Is there any way to preserve positivity in DG methods for elliptic equations?

Preserve positivity: If $f(x)>0 ~\forall x\in\Omega$, then $u(x)>0 ~\forall x\in\Omega$

Edit again: What if the boundary conditions are of zero flux? Edited the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by preserving positivity? Do you mean that $u(x) > 0\ \forall x \in \Omega$?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct. If we take the 1D version of your equation $k \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + u =f$, and take $f=k=1$, the solution is: $u(x) = A \sin(x) + B \cos(x) + 1$. This is positive for some values of $A$ and $B$, but not always.

Comment: Correct -- there is no reason why the solution should be positive. In fact, for particular values of $k$ (the inverse of the eigenvalues of the Laplacian), the equation is singular and there is no unique solution any more.

Comment: Does the situation change if there is zero flux in the boundary?

Comment: Remember to mention the names for the people in the conversation to get notified, like this: @WolfgangBangerth

Comment: Even if the exact solution is positive, there is no guarantee that the numerical solution will be positive, in general. You could probably construct first order schemes that will maintain positivity, but higher order schemes may not.